# How to control speed in JQuery using addClass and removeClass?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using following code for providing pop up title over image hover

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var jq = $.noConflict();
     jq(document).ready(function(){
     jq(".package-images").mouseover(function(){
     jq(this).addClass("title-effect");
     jq(this).addClass("image-effect");
      jq(".package-images").mouseout(function(){
     jq(this).removeClass("title-effect");
      jq(this).removeClass("image-effect");
     });
    });
   });
  </script>
```

It works well, but how can I control the speed of these effects. Basically I want title effect to occur slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the change to be animated over the course of a second:

```
$(this).addClass("title-effect", 1000);
```

If you want the change to be delayed by a second:

```
$(this).delay(1000).addClass("title-effect");
```

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. I tried $(this).addClass("title-effect", 1000); but it does not work. Is there any need for importing javascrit file( some other jquery file).

Comment: @Nida Are you using jQuery-UI or just jQuery?

Comment: I am using only jquery.1.4.2.min.js

Comment: @Nida You tagged your question jquery-ui though. You might want to look into using it:  http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 1):

Look into using the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) method.

**Example:**

```
function changeColor() {
  nIntervId = setInterval(flashText, 500);
}
```

Alternatly, it can be placed as a second parameter of `addClass`:

```
$(this).addClass("title-effect", 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [jQuery UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/) you may set the duration of the animation in the second argument of `addClass()` or `removeClass()`:

```
$(this).addClass("title-effect", 1000);
$(this).removeClass("title-effect", 1000);
```

> **Duration:**
>
> A string or number determining how long the animation will run.